# Why does Django REST Framework return empty list?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, rest, django-rest-framework

On production, we have implemented simple Django REST, which returns all objects from a database:

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'clubs', views.ClubViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^filters/', views.ClubFilterView.as_view())
)
```

views.py:

```
from .serializers import ClubSerializer, ClubFilterSerializer
from .models import (Club, ImageForClub, ClubStaff, ClubFilter,
                     Metro, Rajon, Okrug, Street, Rajon, Rubric, Equipment)
class ClubViewSet(generics.ListAPIView, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Club.objects.filter(latitude__isnull=False)
    throttle_classes = (throttling.ScopedRateThrottle,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('title',)
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer
    pagination_class = None
    paginate_by = None
```

In production, it works just fine. But when I try to deploy it on my local MacBook Air, it starts to behave itself strangely:

in python manage.py shell I can receive objects from the database:

```
In [5]: from apps.clubs.models import Club

In [6]: x = Club.objects.get(pk=1)

In [7]: x
Out[7]: <Club: Pattana Sport>
```

but when I try to send request to Django REST the way on the picture, all I receive is an empty list:

[image]

Despite the fact that the same reguest on production returns list of all objects in database. I'm using the same database - postgres, I dumped and restored the database from production to local computer using this command:

```
$ sudo su - postgres 
$ psql [database_name] << file_dump.sql
```

after that I granted users which Django uses to login by all privileges on this database.

What am I doing wrong? And how to debug this strange behavior? I've checked everything I could...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are filtering items by `latitude__isnull=False` which, i suppose  isn't false for items in your database

Comment: On the contrary, we should get values of clubs, which latitude and longitude are not false. And actually, we have these records in database in the corresponding table: longitude  | latitude  
------------+-----------
  61.399192 | 55.155162

Comment: @paus might be that relations is corrupted after  porting database ?

Comment: In this case, as I think, I wouldn't be able to operate with database objects through Django ORM. But I can receive clubs by id in django shell.

Comment: How to check this assumption?

Comment: check `latitude_set`  of returned object

Comment: Where should I place ipdb in order to catch the returned object? I.e. where does the django_rest_framework instanciate the object?

Comment: I checked the queryset in class, and the first object has latitude: 
ipdb> queryset[1].latitude
Decimal('55.672423')
but it doesn't have latitude_set attribute: queryset[1].latitude_set
*** AttributeError: 'Club' object has no attribute 'latitude_set'

Comment: Does it return something with `queryset = Club.objects.all()`?

Comment: Yes, it returns: [<Club: World Class Власова>, <Club: World Class Lite Варшавка>, <Club: World Class Lady's>, <Club: World Class Город столиц>, <Club: Сибиряк>, <Club: World-Gym>, <Club: Фристайл>, <Club: Авитек>, <Club: XBody>, <Club: НА ВИРАЖЕ>, <Club: Олимпия>, <Club: Gold Fitness>, <Club: Буль-Буль>, <Club: Арбат-фитнес>, <Club: Ника>, <Club: E-MOTION>, <Club: ФизКульт>, <Club: Сакура и Дуб>, <Club: BodyTech Studio>, <Club: Спорт Хаус>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']